# Rcpp modules: Validator function for exposed constructors with same number of parameters

Tags: rcpp

I would like to expose a C++ class with Rcpp modules that has two constructors with the same number of parameters. As documented in the [Rcpp modules](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf) vignette, this can be achieved by using a validator function as the second argument to `.constructor` with the type

```
typedef bool (*ValidConstructor)(SEXP*,int);
```

Could somebody provide an example of how it is supposed to be used? In the vignette, there is only a TODO note that an example should be included there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the disclaimer that I haven't personally used this before, the following appears to work:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class Example {
public:
    Example(int x_, int y_)
        : x(x_), y(y_)
    {
        Rcout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

    Example(std::string x_, std::string y_)
        : x(x_.size()), y(y_.size())
    {
        Rcout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }

    int add() const
    { return x + y; }

private:
    int x, y;
};

bool validate_int_int(SEXP* args, int nargs)
{ return TYPEOF(args[0]) == INTSXP && TYPEOF(args[1]) == INTSXP; }

bool validate_string_string(SEXP* args, int nargs)
{ return TYPEOF(args[0]) == STRSXP && TYPEOF(args[1]) == STRSXP; }

RCPP_MODULE(ExampleMod) {

    class_<Example>("Example")
        .constructor<int, int>(
            "(int, int) constructor",
            validate_int_int
        )
        .constructor<std::string, std::string>(
            "(string, string) constructor",
            validate_string_string
        )
        .method("add", &Example::add)
    ;
}
```

---

Testing from R,

```r
ex.int <- new(Example, 1L, 2L)
# Example::Example(int, int)

ex.string <- new(Example, "one", "two")
# Example::Example(std::string, std::string)

ex.int$add()
# [1] 3

ex.string$add()
# [1] 6
```

---

In each of `validate_int_int` and `validate_string_string` we are just testing the input `SEXP` types against the signatures of their corresponding constructors.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for my use case! I'm just wondering why it is not `&validate_int_int` in `.constructor`?

Comment: @Dominik Pointers to member functions need to be specified with an ampersand, while ordinary (i.e. non-member / free) functions do not; it's just one of those syntax subtleties of C++. There is some more information on [the topic here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types).

Answer (score 5):

To follow up on [nrussell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1869097/nrussell)'s answer, you might want to generate the validators from templates, i.e.

```
template <typename T0, typename T1>
bool typed_valid( SEXP* args, int nargs ){
  return nargs == 2 && Rcpp::is<T0>(args[0]) && Rcpp::is<T1>(args[1]) ;
}
```

which you would use as:

```
.constructor<int, int>( & typed_valid<int,int> )
```

obviously the `typed_valid` function template is straightforward to generalize with variadic templates.

Comment: Thank you for your extension. So pointers to templated functions have to be preceded by `&`, while pointers to free functions not?

Comment: it's just a habit. you might like this talk. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eX9gPithBo about function pointers

Comment: "There is this phenomenal feature in C++, where a function is implicitely convertible to a pointer to itself."

Answer (score 0):

Following the footsteps of previous answers, I found there is a chance that a universal validator function might exist by using variadic template in `cpp`.

The implementation is shorter than I have expected though there are many technical details beyond the scope of this post.

```
template <typename... Types>
bool universal_validator(SEXP* args, int nargs) {
  return universal_validator<Types...>(args, nargs, 0);
}

template <typename T = void, typename... Types>
bool universal_validator(SEXP* args, int nargs, int idx) {
  if (idx>=nargs) return false;

  // optional type traits
  typedef typename Rcpp::traits::remove_const_and_reference<T>::type _Tp;

  return Rcpp::is<_Tp>(args[idx]) && universal_validator<Types...>(args, nargs, idx+1);
}

template <>
bool universal_validator<>(SEXP* args, int nargs, int idx) {
  return nargs == idx;
}
```

The usage of this `universal_validator` is quite simple. Given the `Example` class, the constructors in the `RCPP_MODULE` will become as follows.

```
RCPP_MODULE(example_module) {

  Rcpp::class_<Example>("Example")
  

  .constructor<int, int>("(int, int) constructor", 
                         universal_validator<int, int>)

  .constructor<std::string, std::string> ("(string, string) constructor",
                                          universal_validator<std::string, std::string>)
  .method("add", &Example::add)
  ;
}
```

Just put the same argument types as the constructor in the validator template, e.g. `universal_validator<int, int>` will do the job. And this shall work as long as `Rcpp::is<T>` is defined for any type `T`.

The source code from github
[SEXP newInstance( SEXP* args, int nargs )](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/module/class.h#L123) indicates that the validator must check the types of `SEXP*` and `nargs` simultaneously. That's why not only the type but also the index of `SEXP*` is also checked in all functions.